# Integral extension and field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I came a cross a question that I don't know how to solve

**Problem:** $A,B$ are commutative domains and $A\subseteq B$. Show if that $B$ is a field and every element of $B$ is the root of a non-trivial monic polynomial in $A[x]$, then $A$ is a field.

I don't know how to start on the question.

Comment: Here $\;A\;$ is a subring of $\;B\;$ and $\;x\in B\;$ , right?

Comment: Certainly $A$ is assumed to be a ring with unity. But is it assumed abelian? Or a domain?

Comment: Everything smooths down if $\;A\subset B\;$ , @HagenvonEitzen ... **if** ...

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention the condition. yes both of them are commutative domain and $A$ is a subring of $B$

Comment: This is a particular case  of a much wider and general theorem: if $\;A\subset B\;$ are domains and $\;B\;$ is *integral* over $\;A\;$ , then $\;B\;$ is a field iff $\;A\;$ is a field.

Comment: Is there a counterexample if we only assume that $A,B$ are subrings of a common ring $C$ (as in $A=\mathbb Z[i]$ and $B=\mathbb Q$ - though this doesn't match the monic-polynomial condition)? In that case we no longer *automatically* have that $A$ is a commutative domain ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in A \setminus \{0\}$. By assumption, $a^{-1} \in B$ is well-defined and it is the root of a monic polynomial. Write down such an equation and multiply it with $a^n$, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. Now you will see the inverse of $a$ in $A$.