# Maximal ideal in $\mathfrak{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $\mathfrak{R}$ be a commutative ring with identity. Show that if there exists a monic polynomial $p(x)\in \mathfrak{R}[x]$ of degree at least one such that the ideal $(p(x)) \subseteq\mathfrak{R}[x]$ is maximal, then $\mathfrak{R}$ is a field.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what do you know about the ideals of fields?

Comment: They are only the zero ideal and the field itself.

Comment: It is not- true at all that  $R[x]/(xq(x))\cong R$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks, I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: It's worthy to mention that *monic* is a necessary condition. Otherwise there are examples of polynomials $p$ which generate maximal ideals in $R[X]$, but $R$ is not a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to repeat what I said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1601801/121097):

> If $A$ is a commutative ring and $f\in A[X]$ is a monic polynomial, then the ring extension $A\subset A[X]/(f)$ is integral.

Now use this: [Integral extension and field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030948/integral-extension-and-field).